# List all elements that $P(A)\times P(P(B))$ must contain for any sets $A$ and $B$, where $P(S)$ is the power set of S.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

So I'm confused on where to go with this question, because it says list all elements. I'm not sure how to do that when there are no sets provided. I really want to give it a try on my own, I just have no idea where to start. If you could nudge me in the right direction, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Hint:  $P(A)$ will always contain $\emptyset$ and $A$ as elements regardless what $A$ happens to be, for examples $P(\{1\}) = \{\emptyset, \{1\}\}$ and $P(\{1,2\})=\{\emptyset, \{1\},\{2\},\{1,2\}\}$.  It is open to interpretation whether or not they want you to list those elements of $P(A)\times P(P(B))$ which have $A$ or $B$ appearing in them or not, I would think you should.  You should be able to come up with a list of guaranteed elements of $P(P(B))$, and from there you should be able to come up with a list of guaranteed elements (*ordered pairs*) of $P(A)\times P(P(B))$.

Comment: P(A)×P(P(B))  = {(∅,{∅}) , (∅,{B}) , (∅,{∅,B}) , (∅,∅) , (∅,{∅}) ,(A,{∅}) , (A,{B}) , (A,{A,B}) , (A,∅) , (A,{∅})}      So I went off of what you said, is this a satisfactory listing of all the elements guaranteed?

Comment: I would use equals signs *only* for equality.  You should instead write $P(A)\times P(P(B)) \supseteq \{(\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}),\cdots\}$ instead.  You certainly are on the right track, and it would take me a moment to check if all are there since you seemed to write them in an order I didn't expect.  At a glance, it looks like it might be fine.  You have some duplicated entries however with $(\emptyset, \{\emptyset\})$ and $(A,\{\emptyset\})$ both appearing twice each.

Comment: @JMoravitz I don't like the interpretation that admits expressions in $A$ or $B$ as "sets", because it will be impossible to list them all. Why stop with $\emptyset$ and $A$? $A\cap\mathbb R$ and $A\setminus\mathbb R$ are also guaranteed subsets of $A$. That $A\cap\mathbb R$ might be empty is no objection; $A$ might be empty as well. Also such things as $A\cap P(A)$, $A\cap P(P(A))$, etc. etc. When it comes to guaranteed elements of $P(P(B))$, we have such things as: the set of all finite subsets of $B$, the set of all $3$-element subsets of $B$, etc. ad infinitum.

Comment: @bof you took it many steps further than I think is intended and are advocating for taking it some steps fewer than I think is intended, but as mentioned in my first comment it does appear to be open to interpretation.  I think the answer with eight elements shows more understanding than the answer with only two while the answer with infinitely many is too pedantic to be useful, especially since many of those will be repeats.  The eight can have repeats if A or B are empty but won't if they aren't.

Comment: @JMoravitz I would be hard pressed to come up with a precise statement of the question your list of $8$ sets answers. And I don't see why your list of guaranteed elements of $P(P(B))$ has only $4$ elements and not $8$. If $A$ is a guaranteed element of $P(A)$ then surely $P(B)$ is a guaranteed element of $P(P(B))$. So why don't you list $8$ guaranteed elements of $P(P(B))$, namely $\emptyset$, $\{\emptyset\}$, $\{B\}$, $\{\emptyset,B\}$, $P(B)$, $P(B)\setminus\{\emptyset\}$, $P(B)\setminus\{B\}$, $P(B)\setminus\{\emptyset,B\}$? And then you have to list $16$ elements of $P(A)\times P(P(B))$,

Comment: @bof I agree with that and had not noticed when glancing through the problem and the OP's attempt in the comments that those could (*should?*) have been present.  At this point though, we are just debating semantics. I am of the opinion that the purpose of the problem was mostly to confirm that the student has an understanding of what the format and structure of elements of $P(A)\times P(P(B))$ might be.  To make a clearer question, I might have worded it instead as "*Assuming $A,B$ are non-empty, List at least five unique elements of $P(A)\times P(P(B))$ which are unique regardless of $A,B$*"